# I am getting fatal message i.e not a git repository, when I am typing "git add ." in git command prompt.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github

I wanted to add screen shot of that, but i didn't have that much reputation as I am new to this. I am getting fatal message i.e not a git repository, when I am typing "git add ." in git command prompt. I am currently new to ruby on rails.What should I do?

Comment: have you initialized a git repository for the project?

Comment: thanks! This problem is solved as I deleted some files that was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that when you are executing `git add .` your current directory is not part of the working tree of a git repository.

Make sure that there is a `.git` folder (containing the Git repository) in you current directory or a parent directory of the current directory. If there is not, you need to properly initialize a git repository by `git clone` (if you are starting from some other git repository) or `git init` (if you are starting a new repository).